# Best way to deal with $onAuth maintenance on ionic/angularfire

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm building an app using ionic and angularfire and I didn't understand the logic behind the maintenance of sessions using the $onAuth. I know how the function works, but I do not know exactly where to use it..

Do I need to inject it the $onAuth in every controller and veirfy  if the authData is null or not(to then use $unauth and redirect the user properly) OR there is a way to have this function($onAuth) centralized in an other file and let ir listining and only then do something if the authData is null?

Feel free to ask if the question it's not clear!

Thanks in advance to all who help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways you can take to your goal. The worst one would be to take the way you described and have it in every controller, because you should keep your code [DRY](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself). Your goal clearly is to only write the method for `$onAuth` once.

One easy approach is to have either a `MainController` that is instanciated at the very top of your dom (like on of the outermost html elements, e.g. the body tag). You can then use your child controllers to access data from the parent controller like explained e.g. [here](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication). You would inject the `$onAuth` service in the main controller, and let it do your logic, and you could access the main controller's `$scope` with your `authData` from all its child controllers.

A more reusable part would be to write a service that you can access from all of your controllers. Find a great tutorial here.

The easiest way is to have the `$onAuth` in your module's [run block](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies) and save it in your `$rootScope` that can also be accessed later from all controllers. [Here](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/) is an auth example. You would write

```
angular.module('your-module').run(function($rootScope, Auth) {
  $rootScope.auth = Auth;
  $rootScope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $rootScope.authData = authData;
    //do anything you want here, e.g. redirect
  });
}
```

Comment: "A more reusable part would be to write a service that you can access from all of your controllers. Find a great tutorial here."  I think you forgot a link in this sentence. Besides that your answer is great, pretty clear a many options! thanks a bunch!!